# enctype="multipart/form-data" is not supported to send simple text?

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, servlets

when i m using  enctype="multipart/form-data" in jsp form  the simple text,date,number are not send to servlet it show null values  , when i remove enctype="multipart/form-data"  then form work fine....why...how.....

my jsp code....

```
    <form method="post" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ProfileServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                                                            <input type="text" placeholder="John" name="txtfname" class="form-control"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Doe" name="txtlname" class="form-control"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label">Birth day</label>
                                                            <input type="date" placeholder="Doe" name="txtdate" class="form-control"/>
                                                        </div>
```

Photo

it show null values in servlet using enctype in jsp ,other wise it work fine.....

Comment: why are you trying to use multipart/form-data? Generally this is used when any of your input types are of the type file

Comment: yes i send photo for profile

Comment: are you using spring? Have you declared a multipart handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` form fields aren't available as parameter of the request, you will always get `request.getParameter(name);` as null. They are included in the stream. You can use Apache Commons Fileupload to upload file with other form fields data. In order to use Apache Commons FileUpload, you need to have following files in your webapp's /WEB-INF/lib:

1.) commons-fileupload.jar

2.) commons-io.jar

For ex.

```
if (item.isFormField()) {
    String name = item.getFieldName();
    String value = item.getString();
}
```

Have a look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload//using.html

Comment: yes  your help is used full for me